# What happens when I subscribe to a Timer.Elapsed event more than once?

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling

So I have a System.Timers.timer that ticks for several times only then it is disabled. "Timer.Elapsed" event is subscribed to an Event Handler that counts ticks and disable the timer after certain amount of ticks. Notice that I don't unsubscribe the event.

After several times of subscribing the event to the same Event Handler I realized that ticks intervals are much shorter?

What happens when Timer.Elapsed event is subscribed to an event handler continuously without unsubscribing?

Comment: A memory leak occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are subscribed the event in more then one . every time the function will execute when event will Invoke .

it happens because every function have it on separate copy in delegate functions list;

you can remove unsubscribed the event by using this

```
timer.tick -= yourFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to an event more than once, 10 times for example, then the method bound to that event is triggered 10 times.